# Angular 2 Routing - Open Links from address bar

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When I try to open Angular 2 routes from the address bar I continually receive http 404 responses, however navigating to the routes using anchors with "routerLink" directives works without issue.  I've attempted to modify my web.config file for url rewrites as instructed in [Angular's Deployment Guide](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) but this usually breaks my routing altogether.  Lastly, I did include `<base href="/">` in my index.html file, but this also has not helped.  Any assistance from the community is much appreciated!

Here's my routing component code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientsComponent } from './clients.component';

const routes: Routes = [

    { path: 'clients', component: ClientsComponent },
     //^This does not work from address bar, only from routerLinks.
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },   
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: You can easily solve this issue by enable `#`based routing by saying `[RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]` if you don't need `html5mode` routing

Comment: Thank you Pankaj, this worked, but I'd prefer not to have the # symbol in my urls. Seems like a "hacky" workaround.  Is this just a known issue with Angular 2 and IIS?

Comment: No, this can happen with any server..not specifically with IIS. You have to configure your server to handle such request.. May I know which module loader you're using `systemjs`/`weback`?

Comment: I'm using systemjs.  Also I'm developing with visual studio so I'm debugging using the VS debugger/build system rather than using npm/node

Comment: Are you getting any error in console while you're trying to page directly changing URL?

Comment: No error, just http 404 response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting usehash to true, this should solve your problem.

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

Comment: Thank you Mani, Panaj offered the same in his comment. This solution works, but I'd prefer not to have the # symbol in my urls.

Comment: Ended up enabling "useHash" as I could not figure out a better solution.  Thanks!